# ¿Cómo hacer un salto de línea en pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Estoy haciendo un juego de decisiones. Tengo una cadena de texto muy largo por lo que quiero hacer un salto de línea. Por lo que pongo \n para ello, pero me lo detecta como un carácter y no como salto de línea.

Este es el código del texto:

```
letra20 = pygame.font.Font('Roboto-Thin.ttf', 20)
texto_decision = 'Eres Santiago Nasar, te acabas de levantar \n y te estas preparando para la llegada del obispo.'
texto_completo = letra20.render(texto_decision, True, (255, 255, 255))
texto_rect = texto_completo.get_rect()
texto_rect.center = (WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT // 6)
screen.blit(texto_completo, texto_rect)
```

Comment: probaste a usar triple comilla?

Comment: Tampoco funciona. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Según la [documentación](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render) `pygame.font.Font/SysFont().render()` no soporta textos de más de una línea

Lo que puedes hacer es iterar en las líneas que deseas mostrar y hacer `blit()` a cada línea para mostrarla en la posición correcta

Ejemplo general (Puedes utilizar la función del código siguiente):

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

SIZE = WIDTH, HEIGHT = (1024, 720)
FPS = 30
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE, pygame.RESIZABLE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def render_multi_line(text, x, y, fsize):
        lines = text.splitlines()
        for i, l in enumerate(lines):
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', fsize)
            screen.blit(font.render(l, 0, 0), (x, y + fsize*i))
            
text = "Eres Santiago Nasar, te acabas de levantar\ny te estas preparando para la llegada del obispo."

while True:
    dt = clock.tick(FPS) / 1000
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()
    screen.fill(pygame.Color('white'))
    render_multi_line(text, 10, 10, 15)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Esto produce:

[image: Texto en múltiples líneas]

Answer (score 0):

Lo que dice [otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/531147/158880) es cierto, la documentación indica que el método render no soporta saltos de linea. Sin embargo, seguramente preferirás esta solución si lo que te importa es la velocidad y el texto sufre cambios con poca frecuencia.

---

Si el texto sufre cambios con poca frecuencia, probablemente prefieras más (en nombre de una mayor velocidad) crear una surface con texto de varias líneas guardarla en una variable y dibujarla cuando sea necesario. Esto en contraposición de generar el texto y dibujarlo directamente en pantalla en cada fotograma.

Código de ejemplo (puedes mejorarlo tanto como quieras):

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

def text_surface(font, text, antialias, color, background=None, space_between_lines=0):
    """
    Crea una nueva superficie con texto de multiples lineas.

    font: La fuente (pygame.font.Font)
    text: El texto
    antialias y color: Si se usa antialias y el color del texto. Esto se pasa a font.render para cada linea.
    background: El fondo del texto. Por default es transparente.
    space_between_lines: El espacio entre dos lineas. Por default es 0.
    """
    
    # convertimos el texto en una lista de lineas
    lines = text.splitlines()
    # obtenemos la altura de la fuente
    font_height = font.get_height()

    # obtenemos cual es la cantidad de pixeles de la linea más larga (en pixeles)
    width = max(font.size(line)[0] for line in lines)

    # calculamos la altura que tendrá el texto.
    height = (font_height + space_between_lines) * len(lines) - space_between_lines

    # si no se pasa un background o es None...
    if(background is None):
        # creamos una surface transparente
        surface = pygame.Surface((width, height), flags=pygame.SRCALPHA)
    else:
        # creamos una surface y la llenamos de un solo color.
        surface = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        surface.fill(background)

    y = 0

    # dibujamos cada linea en la surface nueva en la posición correspondiente.
    for line in lines:
        surface.blit(font.render(line, antialias, color), (0, y))
        y += font_height + space_between_lines

    # devolvemos esa surface
    return surface

font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 24)

texto = text_surface(font, "hola\nmundo", antialias=0, color=(255, 255, 255))
texto_con_fondo = text_surface(font, "hola\nmundo", antialias=0, color=(255, 255, 255), background=(200, 200, 200), space_between_lines=20)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
screen.fill((200, 100, 0))


screen.blit(texto, (0, 0))
screen.blit(texto_con_fondo, (100, 0))

pygame.display.flip()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]